# For a new VM I need to set the property enableAutomaticUpdates = false using AZ Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

Trying to create a new VM in Azure using AZ PowerShell.
I want to disable automatic patching and it can be done setting this property:

```
    $vmObj = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmObj -patchMode "Manual" ..
```

When finally calling `New-AzVM ...` to create the VM after setting all properties (among others using `Set-AzVMOperatingSystem ...`) I get this error.

```
New-AzVM : The patchMode 'Manual' is invalid. For patchMode 'Manual', the property 'enableAutomaticUpdates' must be set to false.
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
```

So I have to set the property `enableAutomaticUpdates = false` which I have not been able to set using PowerShell.

The only cmdlet where I can find this property is [Set-AzVmssOsProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmssosprofile?view=azps-7.3.0) but I don't want to create a Virtual Machine Scale Set.

Looking at the `template.json` you get when creating a VM by portal-GUI this property is set like this

```
...
"osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": false,
                        "provisionVmAgent": true,
                        "patchSettings": {
                            "enableHotpatching": "[parameters('enableHotpatching')]",
                            "patchMode": "[parameters('patchMode')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
...
```

Is there a way to set this using PowerShell?

I guess publish the whole PS script will just be noise and it's rather large, but if you think it's valuable I gladly do.

Answer (score 1):

Working on the same issue.

Try this with Set-AzVMOperatingSystem:

-EnableAutoUpdate:$false
(it's a switch parameter)

like this:

$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate:$false -PatchMode Manual

Probably -PatchMode is not necessary if you set EnableAutoUpdate to $false. Read about this while googling but cannot find the article right now :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this for VMs that were created without that property set in the first place. The EnableAutoUpdate property can only be set during the creation of the VM. It is documented in MS doc.

Solution is to create a completely new VM. Then, check the VM template definition (JSON view of the VM in the overview page) and make sure that the EnableAutoUpdate property is set to true.

Next, take a snapshot of the OS disk of the old VM. Create a new managed disk from the snapshot. Then, in the new VM, go to Disk and do a OS disk swap. I've just done this today and I

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but it ssounds likely, thanks for you answer.